# lstrip Method not returning desired result

Tags: python

I can get the desired result for the `lstrip` method, I want to return the names of my SDE Connections without the full path, but `lstrip` doesn't remove all before ArcCatalog. What am I missing? Or is there an easier way?

ie: `C:\Users\an043\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\Transport.sde`
I want to return: `Transport.sde` or `Transport`

This is the code I have been using:

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\an043\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog"
workspacesSDE = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "All")    
for workspaceSDE in workspacesSDE:
    print workspaceSDE.lstrip("ArcCatalog")
```

Comment: This is a pure Python error. The `os.path.basename` function does what you want. The "strip leading character" function would have the same result with an input string of "golatcCrA".

Answer (score 2):

If you were using ModelBuilder you would use the model only tool [Parse path](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/parse-path.htm) to get the desired output. In python as @Vince says you can use the standard python `os` module to resolve this. Example is shown below

```py
import os
aPath = r"C:\Users\an043\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\Transport.sde"

# returns Transport.sde
featureclass = os.path.basename(aPath)
print featureclass

# returns C:\Users\an043\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog
workspace = os.path.dirname(aPath) 
print workspace
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I will be using is:

```
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\an043\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog"
workspacesSDE = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "All")
for workspaceSDE in workspacesSDE:
    print os.path.basename(workspaceSDE)
```

Comment: Please merge your two accounts using these instructions ASAP: http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts